# Storing and getting back files from MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, gridfs

I am working on c# .Net 4.5

I have to upload some files on `MongoDB` and in other module, I have to get them back based on metadata.

for that I am doing like below,

```
    static void uploadFileToMongoDB(GridFSBucket gridFsBucket)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(_sourceFilePath))
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(_uploadedFilePath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(_uploadedFilePath);

            FileInfo[] sourceFileInfo = new DirectoryInfo(_sourceFilePath).GetFiles();

            foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in sourceFileInfo)
            {
                string filePath = fileInfo.FullName;
                string remoteFileName = fileInfo.Name;
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);

                double fileCreationDate = fileInfo.CreationTime.ToOADate();
                GridFSUploadOptions gridUploadOption = new GridFSUploadOptions
                    {
                        Metadata = new BsonDocument
                                    {{ "creationDate", fileCreationDate },
                                    { "extension", extension }}
                    };

                using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
                    gridFsBucket.UploadFromStream(remoteFileName, fileStream, gridUploadOption);
            }
        }
    }
```

and downloading,

```
    static void getFileInfoFromMongoDB(GridFSBucket bucket, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        double startDateDoube = startDate.ToOADate();
        double endDateDouble = endDate.ToOADate();

        var filter = Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.And(
            Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.Gt(x => x.Metadata["creationDate"], startDateDoube),
            Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.Lt(x => x.Metadata["creationDate"], endDateDouble));

        IAsyncCursor<GridFSFileInfo> fileInfoList = bucket.Find(filter); //****

        if (!Directory.Exists(_destFilePath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(_destFilePath);

        foreach (GridFSFileInfo fileInfo in fileInfoList.ToList())
        {
            string destFile = _destFilePath + "\\" + fileInfo.Filename;
            var fileContent = bucket.DownloadAsBytes(fileInfo.Id); //****
            File.WriteAllBytes(destFile, fileContent);
        }
    }
```

in this code (working but) I have two problems which I am not sure how to fix.

- **If i have uploaded a file and I upload it again, it actually gets
  uploaded. How to prevent it?**

Ofcourse both uploaded files have different `ObjectId` but while uploading a file  I will not be knowing that which files are already uploaded. So I want a mechanism which throws an exception if i upload already uploaded file. Is it possible? (I can use combination of filename, created date, etc)

- **If you have noticed in code, actually i am requesting to database server twice to get one file written on disk, How to do it in one shot?**

Note lines of code which I have marked with "//****" comment. First I am querying into database to get fileInfo (`GridFSFileInfo`). I was expecting that I could get actual content of file from this objects only. But I didnot find any related property or method in that object. so I had to do `var fileContent = bucket.DownloadAsBytes(fileInfo.Id);` to get content. M I missing something basic here ?

Comment: For the first issue you can probably use a hash code, which is saved along with the other info. This would ensure you don't keep an exact byte copy of the file. This depends on the size of the file of course. If hashing takes ages use the filename and date combo you proposed.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel can you explain me how and where i can use hash code (or combination of name and date) ?

Comment: Once you have uploaded the file to memory you can run a hash function, e.g. MD5, and save the resulting string along with data. On the next upload you create the hash and compare it to the hashes you already have in the DB. With an index on the hash field this should be reasonably fast. For date and file name, you compare the strings you store along with the data, have indexes on the respective fields.